# ProxyAuthentication fails while updating conda

Tags: proxy, anaconda

I keep getting an error while updating conda:

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.bz2
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

```
ProxyError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: 
/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (
    Caused by ProxyError(
        'Cannot connect to proxy.', 
        OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',)))",
    ),
)
```

A reportable application error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
Upload did not complete.

I tried this in the .condarc file

```
proxy_servers:
  http: http://proxy.corp.local:8080
  https: https://proxy.corp.local:8080
```

and

```
proxy_servers:
    http: http://user:pass@corp.com:8080
    https: https://user:pass@corp.com:8080

ssl_verify: True
ssl_verify: False
```

Regards

Bjorn

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error message and it is solved after googling so much.
Steps for solving the problem is given below

1. Create a `.condrac` file using the conda config command in command prompt or use a text editor to create a text file. I used conda config for creating the `.condrac` file
2. You can add following line into the `.condrac` file located in your user home directory or home 
   directory

proxy_servers:

```
http: http://username:password@proxyIP/Proxy URL:port no
https: http://username:password@proxyIP/ProxyURL:port no
ssl_verify: True
```

3. Same file can be copied into your anaconda home directory.(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 in my case)
4. Then run  > conda update conda command  from your prompt
   Then you will be getting the result like below. `C:\Users\USER.DESKTOP-BQVL8L4>conda update conda`

Solving environment: done

5. Rerun your installation command. This solution worked well for me. Please try and let me know.

Comment: The same error for mein ubuntu while installing glpk.. Guide me to resolve in ubuntu 14.04 with clear directory location.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Copy files libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll and libssl-1_1-x64.dll
from the directory ./Anaconda3/Library/bin/
to ./Anaconda3/DLLs.

This method solved the problem that I had